# set a internal proxy for Youtube API

Tags: java, android, youtube, vpn

Youtube bans my country's IP addresses and we can't access Youtube.
I try to change Skytube which is open-source to access Youtube without an external VPN or proxy App.
I'm going to rent a server in another country to create an OpenVPN or PPTP VPN.
can I create an intenal-app VPN that only tunnels my youtube traffic into VPN? how?
or I must Add a Proxy java class over NetHttpTransport? and how I do it?

This is the method that initializes Youtube Connection in Skytube:

```
public static YouTube create() {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = AndroidJsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            private String getSha1() {
                String sha1 = null;
                try {
                    Signature[] signatures = SkyTubeApp.getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
                    for (Signature signature: signatures) {
                        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

                        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                        sha1 = BaseEncoding.base16().encode(md.digest());
                    }
                } catch (Throwable tr) {
                    Logger.e(this, "...", tr);
                }
                return sha1;
            }
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                request.getHeaders().set("X-Android-Package", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
                request.getHeaders().set("X-Android-Cert", getSha1());
            }
        }).setApplicationName("+").build();
    }
```